# How to evaluate $\iint (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot d \vec a$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

> C is the curve arising from the intersection of the elliptic cylinder $\frac{(x-2)^2}{36} + \frac{(y-1)^2}{9} = 1$ and the plane $3x + y + z = 1$, which circulates counterclockwise as seen from above. $\vec F = (2z^2 + y^2 + sin(x^2))\hat{i} + (2xy + z)\hat{j} + (xz + 2yz)\hat{k}$

I want to get the flux through the surface enclosed by the boundary $C$. So as to do so, let's use Stoke's Theorem:

$$\iint_{S} (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot n \frac{\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy}{|n \cdot k|} = \oint_{C} \vec F \cdot \mathrm d \vec l$$

I want to solve the problem evaluating the left hand side of ST. I have tried the following:

the projection of the enclosed surface on the $xy$ plane is the given ellipse. So we indeed need to get a unit normal vector of that ellipse:

$$n = \nabla \left(\frac{(x-2)^2}{4} + (y-1)^2\right) = \frac{x-2}{2} \hat{i} + 2(y-1) \hat{j}$$

$$\hat{n} = \frac{\frac{x-2}{2} \hat{i} + 2(y-1) \hat{j}}{\sqrt{\frac{(x-2)^2}{4}+ 4(y-1)^2}}$$

I guess there has to be a way of simplifying $\hat{n}$ but don't see it :(

So now we just have to set up the integral:

$$\iint (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \mathrm d \vec a = \iint \left[(2z - 1)\hat{i} + 3z\hat{j}\right]\left[\frac{\frac{x-2}{2}\hat{i} + 2(y-1)\hat{j}}{\sqrt{\frac{(x-2)^2}{4}+ 4(y-1)^2}}\right] \mathrm da$$

Now we gotta make a change of variables so as to go from an ellipse to a circle centred at the origin.

Rearranging the curve we get:

$$\frac{(x-2)^2}{36} + \frac{(y-1)^2}{9} = 1$$

Using the following change of variables and using it:

\begin{align}
x - 2 &= 6u \\
y - 1 &= 3v \\
u^2 + v^2 &= 1
\end{align}

Don't forget the Jacobian! :)

$$\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial (u, v)} = 18$$

$$-18\iint \left[(36u+6v+13)\hat{i} + (36u+9v+12)\hat{j}\right]\left[\frac{\frac{6u}{2}\hat{i} + 2(3v)\hat{j}}{\sqrt{\frac{(6u)^2}{4}+ 4(3v)^2}}\right]\mathrm du\, \mathrm dv$$

There's just one step left: apply the last change of variables (polar coordinates):

$$u = r\cos\theta\\
v = r\sin\theta$$

**I've been told this is wrong, but don't get why. Please explain how to evaluate** $\iint (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \mathrm d \vec a$.

Comment: I assume you mean the region in the plane $3 x + y + z = 1$ enclosed by $C$, since $C$ by itself doesn't define a surface. Your $\mathbf n$ doesn't have a $\mathbf k$ component, it's a normal to the cylinder, not to the plane. The flux of $\mathbf F$ is $\iint_D \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf S$, maybe you want the flux of $\nabla \times \mathbf F$, not of $\mathbf F$?

Comment: @Maxim That is correct. I am looking for the flux through the plane which is enclosed by $C$. I understand that by Stokes' theorem, that surface can be whatever I want while the boundary C doesn't change. After some though I think the correct approach is to take the normal to the plane (easiest surface to work with) and use $$\iint_{S} (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot n \frac{\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy}{|n \cdot k|}$$ to get the flux. Do you agree? (Note that on my original post I insisted on taking the normal to the ellipse. That is wrong, because what we want is the normal to the *enclosed* surface)

Comment: Yes, I was a bit confused because you said "to get the flux", and the flux of $\mathbf F$ does depend on which surface you choose. Also, there isn't a uniquely defined normal to the ellipse, it's a space curve.

Your derivation is correct though, you just need to evaluate (continued)

Comment: $$\iint_D (\nabla \times \mathbf F) \cdot d\mathbf S =
\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1
 \frac {(\nabla \times \mathbf F) \cdot \mathbf n} {|\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf k|}
 \bigg\rvert_{(x, y, z) = \mathbf r(\rho, \phi)}
 18 \rho \,d\rho d\phi, \\
\mathbf r(\rho, \phi) =
(2 + 6 \rho \cos \phi,
 1 + 3 \rho \sin \phi,
 1 - 3 (2 + 6 \rho \cos \phi) - (1 + 3 \rho \sin \phi)),$$
where $\mathbf n$ is a normal to the plane $3 x + y + z = 1$.